# Inserting characters into an INT field with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlfiddle

I've made a fiddle in SQL fiddle and am trying to display a list of numbers 1-99. I also want the numbers to be replaced with text if certain conditions are met. I have implemented the conditions but cannot input text since the column is an INT field. I have tried using CAST prior to the conditions but this only caused SQL fiddle to crash. I also tried changing the whole column to VARCHAR but I encountered the same result.

Any help is appreciated! The link to the fiddle is below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/691f2/1

EDIT**WORKING CODE**

```
CREATE TABLE numbers(
    numbers int
    );

DECLARE @start as int
SET @start = 1
DECLARE @plus as int
SET @plus = 1
DECLARE @end as int
SET @end = 99

BEGIN TRANSACTION
WHILE (@start <= @end)
BEGIN INSERT INTO numbers 
values (@start) SET @start += @plus
END COMMIT TRANSACTION;

UPDATE numbers
SET numbers = '3737'
WHERE numbers%3 = 0 AND numbers%7 = 0;

UPDATE numbers
SET numbers = '3333'
WHERE numbers%3 = 0;

UPDATE numbers
SET numbers = '7777'
WHERE numbers%7 = 0;

SELECT (CASE numbers
WHEN 3333 THEN 'Open'
WHEN 7777 THEN 'Source'
WHEN 3737 THEN 'OpenSource'
ELSE CAST(numbers as VARCHAR)
END) AS Numbers
FROM numbers;
```

Comment: You don't. Ideally, you do this kind of presentational formatting in your presentation layer, not down in the database. Fundamentally, a column of type `int` contains integers. That's it.

Comment: You can't store non-numerical values in a numerical datatype. You should also avoid combining data types. If you need to store textual data, store it as a`varchar` in a different column.

Comment: Use `CASE`, for example, when SELECTING from the table to show the "replacements"

Comment: Okay I've used CASE in a select statement but even I add "ELSE numbers" it says it can't convert VARCHAR to INT.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/691f2/5

Comment: sqlfiddle seems to be down at the moment. But it sounds like you are trying to change the datatype of a column on each row. You can't do this. A column can have one and only datatype across the entire result set. It can't be an int on one row and character data on the next.

Comment: Post the code of your attempt to change the whole column to varchar in the text of your question.   This would work if you did it correctly.

Comment: `CASE` is an expression. It returns a *value*. That value has to be of a certain data type. This means that you cannot mix datatypes in your `THEN` and `ELSE` expressions (well, you can but then SQL Server tries to force things to the data type with the highest precedence - `int`). So if you want strings, and you want them to stay as strings, make sure any value that `CASE` might try to return is a string and not a number.

Comment: @damien_the_unbeliever so that is why the else statement didn't work since said to return the values for the numbers column which is INT. What if I made two columns, how would I go about merging them?

Comment: @tab SQLFiddle is down at the moment but once it is working again I will post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if I made two columns, how would I go about merging them?

If you want to merge the values of an `int` column and a `varchar` column into one column, you have to cast the `int` as `varchar`, since string values can't be cast as `int`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using a CASE statement with an ELSE statement and CAST statement. Here is a link to the fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/691f2/23. Is this what you meant with your answer or should I make a new answer?

Comment: @HassanNaveed I don't follow links so if you can't add the code to your question I cannot see it.

Comment: @HassanNaveed Yes, what you have done is exactly what I meant.